# MySQL Stored Procedure Delimiter Error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement a stored procedure to create a snapshot of the user's balances and I always get an error in line 5, that the syntax is wrong and I haven't found an answer to what is wrong with this syntax:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createSnapshot;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE createSnapshot()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO balance_history (uid,coin_id,balance) SELECT uid,coin_id,amount FROM balance;

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT primary_key,timestamp FROM balance_history WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY); 

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

DECLARE id INT;

DECLARE time1 TIMESTAMP;

OPEN cursor1;

read_loop: LOOP;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF

    FETCH cursor1 INTO id,time1;
END LOOP

CLOSE cursor1;
END//
```

DELIMITER ;

Comment: Have you tried declaring your variables before doing any queries? Also ["Variable declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html); so you at very least need to move `id` and `time1` declarations sooner.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL stored procedures, functions, etc.. have some rules about where variables may be DECLAREd. Typically, the start of a block is best; though certain types of local variables must be declared after others.

[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) is a good reference to start with in the MySQL documentation when looking for specifics.